# Spring RestTemplate, can I retrieve a specific single field from the obtained JSON response avoiding to declare a model class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am working on a Spring Boot project performing REST call to an external API in this way:

```
@Override
public List<NotaryDistrictDetails> getNotaryDistrictDetailsByDistictId(String districtId) throws URISyntaxException {
    
    String completeURL =  this.wpPortalBasicNotaryDistrictPostBaseURL.replace("{districtId}", districtId);
    System.out.println("completeURL: " + completeURL);
    
    URI uri = new URI(completeURL);
    System.out.println(uri);
    
    ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
    
    System.out.println(forEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
    System.out.println(forEntity.getBody());
    
    
    return null;
}
```

At the moment the println output is something like this (and this is correct):

```
200
[{"post_type":"notary-district","ID":38804,"wpcf-idnotary-district":"XXX","post_title":"AA"}]
```

I know that to retrieve a specific field I can create a model object containing these fields and then do something like:

```
ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, MyModelClass.class);
```

and then retrieve all my properties.

but in this case I have only to retrieve the value of a single specific field from the previous JSON repsonse, the **ID** field, this one **"ID":38804**. This because I have rto use this retrieved value to perform a second external API call passing this ID as paramether.

My question is: exist a way to directly retrieve a single field value (in this case the ID field value) avoiding to create a model class for this response? Or have I to create a model class and retrieve the whole object related to my response and from here retrieve the ID field?

Comment: If you’re using Jackson, just use JsonNode (ArrayNode or ObjectNode if you know specifically what the JSON is) then traverse the JSON manually until you find the member you want.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment of my original post I solved using **JsonNode** Jackson object, following my solution:

```
@Override
public List<NotaryDistrictDetails> getNotaryDistrictDetailsByDistictId(String districtId) throws URISyntaxException, JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    
    String completeURL =  this.wpPortalBasicNotaryDistrictPostBaseURL.replace("{districtId}", districtId);
    System.out.println("completeURL: " + completeURL);
    
    URI uri = new URI(completeURL);
    System.out.println(uri);
    
    ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
    
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(forEntity.getBody());
    
    System.out.println("jsonNode: " + jsonNode.get(0).toPrettyString());
        
    System.out.println("ID: " + jsonNode.get(0).get("ID"));

    
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```java
ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>> responseType =
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};

ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> responseEntity = 
        restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, responseType);
```

Then get the required value by key